# Copy header from MS Word to Excel

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have an Excel VBA code that copies the content of the MS word file:

```
'Open PDF file in MS Word
Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(PDFfilepath, ConfirmConversions:=False, ReadOnly:=False)
With wordDoc
         Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = convertSheetName
        .Range(.Content.Start, .Content.End).Copy
End With

wordApp.Quit
convertedFile_Wb.Activate
Sheets(convertSheetName).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A1").Select
Sheets(convertSheetName).Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Sheets(convertSheetName).Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit
```

How to copy all data including headers and footers even if they are blank or not and paste all of it to Excel?

I don't know if this have something to do with sections in Word.

Comment: Including headers/footers needs some more specification: How would you like the page-based headers/footers to appear in Excel? What if your Word document contains sections (i.e. multiple different headers/footers). What to do if you have different first page or odd/even headers/footers in your document? At the moment you question is too broad to be answered.

Comment: The header/footer in Word is just plain text might as well be copied like that. If the PDF file is opened in Word, it creates sections (eg. Header -Section 9-). What I want is to copy as is what it's like in Word to Excel.

Comment: Your request is still not making any sense. If you mean to entirely recreate the Word document in Excel (whatever for?), as it appears on-screen or when printed, then you need to loop every section, determine which headers/footers are defined for the section, figure out where each page breaks so that you can associate the correct header/footer (first page, odd page) and essentially transfer the information bit-by-bit. Assuming that's what you want, this is enough to get you started, but people get paid for working things like this out and writing the amount of code involved - it's not trivial!

Comment: Yes, that is what I want, re-create what is seen in the Word document to Excel. I was just hoping someone to help me out even a little bit because this is my current impediment and I just started learning Excel VBA.

Comment: Well, I wrote the steps required - you have to do some research, yourself, now, as to the Word object model required. What you want goes well beyond the scope of the StackOverflow Q&A format - the question is "too broad". There's certainly no way to copy/paste in one single step, or even a single step / page.